# Same query cached by mysql5.6 but not 5.7

Tags: mysql, query-performance, query-cache

Both server almost have identical configuration.

They both took the query below about 1sec to finish. Same "explain" and "profile" info.

```
SELECT
    action.id
FROM
    ow_newsfeed_action action
INNER JOIN ow_newsfeed_activity activity ON action.id = activity.actionId
INNER JOIN ow_newsfeed_activity cactivity ON action.id = cactivity.actionId
INNER JOIN `ow_base_user` base_user_table_alias ON base_user_table_alias.`id` = `cactivity`.`userId`
LEFT JOIN `ow_base_user_suspend` base_user_suspend_table_alias ON base_user_suspend_table_alias.`userId` = `base_user_table_alias`.`id`
WHERE
    (
        `base_user_suspend_table_alias`.`id` IS NULL
    )
AND (
    `base_user_table_alias`.`emailVerify` = 1
)
AND action.privacy = 'everybody'
AND action.featured = 1
AND activity. TIMESTAMP < 1469064603
GROUP BY
    action.id
ORDER BY
    MAX(activity. TIMESTAMP) DESC
LIMIT 0,
 10
```

But only mysql5.7 doesn't cache it. Here is the profile I got from phpmyadmin

```
1   Starting    16 µs
2   Waiting For Query Cache Lock    3 µs
3   Starting    2 µs
4   Checking Query Cache For Query  93 µs
5   Checking Permissions    4 µs
6   Checking Permissions    2 µs
7   Checking Permissions    1 µs
8   Checking Permissions    2 µs
9   Checking Permissions    3 µs
10  Opening Tables  184 µs
11  Init    43 µs
12  System Lock 12 µs
13  Waiting For Query Cache Lock    3 µs
14  System Lock 23 µs
15  Optimizing  17 µs
16  Statistics  145 µs
17  Preparing   25 µs
18  Creating Tmp Table  22 µs
19  Sorting Result  6 µs
20  Executing   2 µs
21  Sending Data    879.2 ms
22  Creating Sort Index 194 µs
23  End 5 µs
24  Query End   8 µs
25  Removing Tmp Table  7 µs
26  Query End   2 µs
27  Closing Tables  12 µs
28  Freeing Items   23 µs
29  Cleaning Up 14 µs
```

If I remove the joins to user tables, it is faster and cached by mysql (5.7).. any suggestion?

Comment: Lots of things can invalidate a cached query including changes to the underlying tables. At any rate the profile you've shown has microseconds for everything except transporting the resultset from the MySQL server to the client. Please [edit] your question to be more specific.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT...` on each version.